# How to verify prices in real time

Tags: java, android, parsing, new-operator

I've been breaking my head for a few days and can not seem to reach a creative solution.
I'm building a price comparison app.
I have about 50 stores, each holding the same products, for example: milk, bread, meat.
A user enters my application, selects a category, for example milk, and once he has chosen a product, I have to go through all the shops and check where the cheapest milk is.

My question is, how do the verification prices in the most efficient way.

I thought of such an idea:
Hold all the stores in the array, all products hold JSON file and give each product ID.
Once the user selects the product, run all the array stores.
The question of how to pull from them the prices? How to do the PARSING.
Ideas?

This is an example site that illustrates exactly what I want to do.
https://www.zapmarket.co.il/fruits_vegetables
Translate it to english=]

Comment: I think you need a backend sever which will keep all the periodically updated data & will provide a secure api.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of holding the stores in the array, hold a product class with all the attributs needed. Then you can sort by price and get the store